# Remove outer tags but keep inside ones

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, umbraco7

I'm trying to remove outer p tags if there is another tag inside, the rest of the p tags should be kept. (The last line in the code block below).

```
<p><img id="__mcenew" src="/media/1902/agf.jpg" alt="" rel="11861" /></p>
<p><h1>Nyt design formidler oplevelserne</h1></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In a erat et quam luctus tincidunt. Mauris convallis mattis sapien, eu laoreet lectus tempus vitae. Duis bibendum feugiat neque, eget porta purus egestas at. Mauris a libero et risus pretium efficitur ut nec diam. In rutrum maximus condimentum. Donec id est turpis. Sed nulla magna, dignissim at tellus sed, pretium pharetra ante. Suspendisse dolor est, gravida sed ultricies non, tempus sed elit.</span></p>
<p><h1>Nyt design formidler oplevelserne</h1></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In a erat et quam luctus tincidunt. Mauris convallis mattis sapien, eu laoreet lectus tempus vitae. Duis bibendum feugiat neque, eget porta purus egestas at. Mauris a libero et risus pretium efficitur ut nec diam. In rutrum maximus condimentum. Donec id est turpis. Sed nulla magna, dignissim at tellus sed, pretium pharetra ante. Suspendisse dolor est, gravida sed ultricies non, tempus sed elit.</p>
```

This is how I want it to look:

```
<img id="__mcenew" src="/media/1902/agf.jpg" alt="" rel="11861" />
<h1>Nyt design formidler oplevelserne</h1>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In a erat et quam luctus tincidunt. Mauris convallis mattis sapien, eu laoreet lectus tempus vitae. Duis bibendum feugiat neque, eget porta purus egestas at. Mauris a libero et risus pretium efficitur ut nec diam. In rutrum maximus condimentum. Donec id est turpis. Sed nulla magna, dignissim at tellus sed, pretium pharetra ante. Suspendisse dolor est, gravida sed ultricies non, tempus sed elit.</span>
<h1>Nyt design formidler oplevelserne</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In a erat et quam luctus tincidunt. Mauris convallis mattis sapien, eu laoreet lectus tempus vitae. Duis bibendum feugiat neque, eget porta purus egestas at. Mauris a libero et risus pretium efficitur ut nec diam. In rutrum maximus condimentum. Donec id est turpis. Sed nulla magna, dignissim at tellus sed, pretium pharetra ante. Suspendisse dolor est, gravida sed ultricies non, tempus sed elit.</p>
```

Any help is appreciated, I've tried a few things out in JS/JQuery and Razor/C#, but i'm stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using jQuery unwrap() method.

for images:

```
$("#maincontent img").unwrap();
```

for span:

```
$("#maincontent span").unwrap();
```

Also changes span tags to p tags using (not in the question, but part of the solution to the problem I had):

```
$("#maincontent span").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $html = $this.html();
    $this.replaceWith("<p>" + $html + "</p>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
("body p")
.html()
    .appendTo("body")
.end()
.remove();
```

This should remove all <p> in the body of your document